# URL rewrite in OWIN middleware

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, owin

I have a problem with URL rewriting which works in Global.asax but not in OWIN middleware.

Global.asax code

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest()
{
    //Perfectly working rewrite. 
    //By route rules, this resolves to the action Global()
    //of the HomeController
    HttpContext.Current.RewritePath("Home/Global");
}
```

OWIN middleware code (used for culture detection, code shortened for brevity)

```
public class GlobalizationMiddleware : OwinMiddleware
{
    public GlobalizationMiddleware(OwinMiddleware next)
        : base(next)
    { }

    public async override Task Invoke(IOwinContext context)
    {
        context.Request.Path = new PathString("/Home/Global");
        await Next.Invoke(context);
    }
}
```

I expect that "Global" action of the controller "Home" gets called...but instead, the default action "Index" is called.

After the Path is changed `context.Request.Uri.AbsoluteUri` is `http://localhost/Global/Home`

But Controller's `Request.Url.AbsoluteUri` is still `http://localhost`

I even tried `context.Environment["owin.RequestPath"] = "/Home/Global";` but that doesn's seem to work either.

Before anyone asks, yes, I call the `IAppBuilder.Use(typeof(GlobalizationMiddleware))` in Startup.cs and the debugger enters the Invoke method.

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT**

I even tried referencing `System.Web` and then doing this...doesn't work either :(

```
System.Web.Routing.RequestContext requestContext = context.Environment["System.Web.Routing.RequestContext"] as System.Web.Routing.RequestContext;
requestContext.HttpContext.RewritePath("/Home/Global");

System.Web.HttpContextBase contextBase = context.Environment["System.Web.HttpContextBase"] as System.Web.HttpContextBase;
contextBase.RewritePath("/Home/Global");
```

**EDIT 2 - Found a working solution (see below) but I'm unsure whether it's the right solution, comments would be appreciated :)**

Comment: Why do you need a Rewrite, and why doesn't IIS Url Rewriter work for your situation?

Comment: IIS Url Rewriter might work for my use case, I'm not sure... I just got drown in this problem so I posted it, I hope that's not a problem :) My use case is that I have several domains pointing on my website (each domain has different business logic configuration) and one "directory" domain, which is just a list of links to those available domains. If I access a domain which is no longer listed or the domain does not pass various business assertions about its configuration, I want to show the "directory" domain instead...which is basically just a different view with different layout.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found a working solution.

Unfortunately, I needed to include System.Web. I'm directly altering the RouteData object in the RequestContext.

```
System.Web.Routing.RequestContext requestContext = context.Environment["System.Web.Routing.RequestContext"] as System.Web.Routing.RequestContext;
requestContext.HttpContext.RewritePath("Home/Global");
requestContext.RouteData.Values["action"] = "Global";
```

But this feels too hacky to my tastes... I'm not sure if this is the right solution so I won't accept this as the valid answer, maybe someone will come with a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this as well, and found that one way to get this working is just to use `HttpContext`

```
HttpContext.Current.RewritePath("/new/path");
```

If you're already including `System.Web` anyway this seems to be a workable solution.

---

OWIN is a layer on top of ASP.NET (System.Web), and some of the ASP.NET components (such as MVC) are not built on top of OWIN but actually ASP.NET directly.

Looking deeper, `OwinRequest` doesn't have any reference to `System.Web.HttpContext` and instead just deals with `Environment` ([source](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetKatana/blob/e2b18ec84ceab7ffa29d80d89429c9988ab40144/src/Microsoft.Owin/OwinContext.cs#L41)), so that's why setting the OWIN request path doesn't affect ASP.NET apps.